# Angular Reactive Forms - Repeat objects

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular10

I am a newbie to Angular 10 (jumped from Angularjs to Angular) and I am facing some problems

I have a multiple objects in database like this :

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "search_name" : "example search name",
  "link" : "https://link",
  "label": {
    "label_uk" : "UK Label",
    "label_us" : "US Label",
    },
  "description" : {
    "description_uk": "",
    "description_us":""
  }
}
```

I am trying to build a repeat form for each object, so for each key I need to edit in the form :
example :

```
formGroup.addControl('link', new FormControl(object.link));
```

my question: how to keep the id without create a control for it ( Because I wont edit it)?
Should I create control for each key in model ? (I want edit only some)
How to know my model ?

Thank you and sorry if my question is not clear!

Comment: Since you are using reactive form it's good to create formControl even though you are not going to change. So that assosiated values will be grouped together in single formGroup.

Comment: So if I have a big object with 40 keys for example and iwant edit 5 of them for example I should create 40 controls in my formGroup ? thank you

Comment: you want to show all 40 keys control in UI?

Comment: not all but i want use some of keys for others things like show title or create link with the href ... but not as form control ( input, select...)

Comment: Then you can store id in form Group then map the object based on formGroup id control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose the two aproach, the good of create a FormGroup with all the "properties", allow you use the same FormGroup when you want to make a new "object".

e.g. One function like

```
getFormGroup(data:any=null)
{
   data=data || {id : 0, search_name : null,link:null,label:null,description:null}
   return new FormGroup({
      id:new FormControl(data.id),
      search_name:new FormControl(data.search_name),
      link:new FormControl(data.link),
      label:data.label?new FormGroup({
          label_uk:new FormControl(data.label.label_uk),
          label_us:new FormControl(data.label.label_us),
      }):
                       new FormGroup({
          label_uk:new FormControl(null),
          label_us:new FormControl(null),
      })
      description:data.description?new FormGroup({
          description_uk:new FormControl(data.description.description_uk),
          description_us:new FormControl(data.description.description_us),
      }):
                       new FormGroup({
          description_uk:new FormControl(null),
          description_us:new FormControl(null),
      })
     
   })
}
```

Allow you create the formGroup using

```
this.myForm=this.getFormGroup()  //an empty
this.myForm=this.getFormGroup(this.data)  //a data
```

But, As you say, it's innecesary is you has an object with 40 fields and you only need change 5 of them. You can use two functions

```
getNewFormGroup(){
   this.state="new"
   return .....
}

getUpdateFormGroup(data){
      this.state="update"
      return new FormGroup({
          search_name:new FormControl(data.search_name),
          link:new FormControl(data.link),
          label:new FormGroup({
              label_uk:new FormControl(data.label.label_uk),
              label_us:new FormControl(data.label.label_us),
          })
}
```

Remember a FormGroup (and his value exist event if you has no an html input)